# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError JavaMail Tomcat v8.5

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, classnotfoundexception, tomcat8.5

I'am trying to send an automatic email with JavaMail on Oracle. I added external JARs on Java Build Path  (`mail.jar` and `activation.jar`). I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I get this error message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.internet.AddressException
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
```

I'm using Tomcat v8.5.

Comment: The error suggests that the JavaMail jar is not on the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add [Javax mail](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.4) dependency to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the JavaMail library Jars either to the Tomcat `lib` folder, or it has to be part of your WAR file when you deploy your WebApp. Adding it to the Build Path makes it only available during compile time. Although, depending on the configuration for the Deployment, it could be deployed, too – but obviously, not in your case.